# is it possible to override/disable the functionality of the iPhone power button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

After getting my iPhone stolen several times, i thought a utility app that would only allow a user to power off the iPhone if he/she has passed the authorization screen (keycode/fingerprint). This would leave a good amount of time for the owner to be able and track their phone and would prevent thiefs from turning it off so findmyiphone won't work.

I asked on the ios developer forums but no answer. I know that it will most likely not get authorized in the appstore (at least for now), but would still love the functionality on my phone and hopefully others.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Only with a jailbreak.

Comment: Probably not even with a jailbreak. Power + home + time will force shutdown on a hung OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly with a jailbreak. But i'm pretty sure that the api's aren't exposed, and the functionality would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible, period!

There is only one button in the device and you want to disable it, come on, and how do you feel if you get an app you can not dismiss it?

Comment: I count 4 buttons, and it's not impossible.

Comment: dude, if you are counting the button like this they are five not four :P, and yes it is impossible in a legal way, it is a kind of hack you don't want in your device.

Comment: @null the idea is not disable the power button completely...only to force a user to be "logged-in" to his device for it to work. That way, unauthorized users will not be able to shut-off your phone. Why would you want to allow someone else to shut off your phone?

Comment: @RoyH yes I got you but what I mean is what if Apple opened this function for public? and every application has its own implementation for this interceptor?!. Plus if the thief has physical access to your mobile then good luck preventing him to do whatever he wants ;)

Comment: @null apple still has the app store review process in which they can check how you used your functionality...same as them not authorizing apps that don't follow guidelines when tapping on a screen. Most of these thief's don't have immediate access to a computer so they can't really format it instantly. Blocking their ability to shut of your device will certainly help in attempts to recover it. I don't think you can argue with that, but I appreciate the feedback and involvement!